# Managing Order journey with reviews

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder, order

I created a data extension to capture customer data and other data extension to have order details. This data is updated daily.
I created an attribute group with below links:
Contact key relates to subscriberkey in customer’s DE ( 1 to 1 relation). Subscriberkey relates to subscriberkey in Order’s DE ( 1 to  many relationship).

I created a journey and use 3rd data extension customer data with product details as entry source. Used decision split with attribute to attribute comparison but split doesn't work. Also tried with normal data in decision split by manually entering the product name, still doesn't work.

[image: data designer attribute group]

Actual use case: Subscribers place orders through website. These details are captured in SFMC 2 DEs (1 Customer details & 2 order details). After subscriber places an order, we will send an email for order review. If the subscriber review with 4 or 5 stars, we want to send him coupons else asking him for more feedback. (Note: also want to make sure that subscriber should not receive email if they reviewed a product twice).

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that helped was to use Query activities (had to use 3 or more) to filter out and add new column values to the data. This way we  don't need to use Contact Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, you needed to add this 3rd Data Extension to the Attribute Group as well and then use it in the Decision Split in the Journey. This way you would have been able to filter out some records correctly.

The thing is if you are using "Data_Extension_A" as an Entry Source and then use "Data_Extension_B" and "Data_Extension_C" in the Decision Split, then absolutely, it will not work, since there is no connection with "Data_Extension_A".